# I/flutter ( 4037): The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I am getting an error trying to run this code about the method '[]' being null. Is it maybe the list view? The output doesn't even show up in debug console anymore. Sorry I'm new to this.

**The code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class GetStats extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GetStatsState createState() => _GetStatsState();
}

class _GetStatsState extends State<GetStats> {
  Map data;

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(
            'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=D5F4E0DED484F47380C2804A529BAEDC&steamid=76561198406742636'),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    setState(() {
      data = json.decode(response.body);
    });
    print(data["playerstats"]["stats"][0]["value"]);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('CSGO STATS'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            int index,
          ) {
            return Card(
              child: Text(
                data["playerstats"],
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
I/flutter ( 4037): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4037): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
I/flutter ( 4037): The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 4037): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 4037): Tried calling: []("playerstats")
I/flutter ( 4037):
I/flutter ( 4037): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to initialize something?

Comment: The variable ``data`` is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making correct `http` request and getting data too
However the problem lies in your widget , I checked the API response it is throwing a response of `Map<String,dynamic>`
While displaying the data you are accessing the data using `playerstats` key which in turn is giving you a `Map` which is not a `String` as required by `Text` Widget in order to display it !

You can display the `data` by simply converting it to String by using `toString()` method like this

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('CSGO STATS'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            int index,
          ) {
            return Card(
              child: Text(
                data["playerstats"].toString(),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

Also, I would like to suggest you some Improvements in your Code

- Use type annotation as much as possible, It makes your code more safe and robust , Like you have declared `data` variable as `Map data;` , You should declare it like `Map<String,dynamic> data;`
- I think you forget to call `super.initState()` in your `initState()` method , Make sure to call it before all your methods.
- Method `getData` doesn't return anything, So make it as `Future<void>` instead of `Future<String>`

Since you are new contributor to StackOverflow , I welcome you !
Happy Fluttering !

Answer (score 0):

data["playerstats"] is a Map while the Text widget needs String.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is ok, but the problem is in initiating the text widget.

```
child: Text(
            data["playerstats"],
          ),
```

`['playerstats']` is not a single text, its a map of list. You need to specify the exact text field  name you want to see. Still it will show you full data if you add `.toString()` with the field name.